# Translate an HTML document in multiple languages

Tags: javascript, html, translate

I've just started a new job where I am coding emails daily in multiple languages, and I am hoping to come across a solution to make my work efforts a bit more streamlined. Essentially I create an English HTML email and then copy and paste the exact HTML into another document and translate the text to say, German or French. Does anyone know of a solution to translate an entire HTML document to another language, obviously only the main content? I came across this Azure tool that does it, but it's a bit complicated for me to understand. Is there a Javascript function to do this?  Any direction would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate has a free HTML page translator you can find [here](https://wcmshelp.ucsc.edu/advanced/google-translate.html). It does look ugly in my opinion, but it works perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
// ]]></script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/bsru1823/2/

Comment: Although this is a great solution for webpage translations what I am looking for is a platform to upload my HTML document and exporting a translated HTML document with all the HTML tags perfect.